# Github restricting access

Tags: git, version-control, github

I am using github.

I'm trying to figure out how to restrict repo access for a contractor i have.

I have the main rails codebase and i also have a contractor that will be doing some css/ux type work for me.

I want to give the contractor the ability to check in code to git hub only to certain folders.

Ideally, i can have him checkin code and then it can be deployed out to the server so that he can see the changes.

I don't think i can do this via limiting access within a specific git repo, but maybe there is a way to use two repo's and restrict access that way.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If the contractor only has access to certain folders how can he test what he's doing?

Comment: the goal would be that he's only editing css look and feel. so he's only editing css classes. so if the css is autodeployed, he should be able to see it when he hits the running application.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If all of the css/ux files are within a particular subfolder, and you want him to have access to everything in that directory, and further down, you could do it with git submodules.

The contractor would have push/pull rights to the repo that is a submodule, but no commit rights on the main repo.

You could also just use the pull request feature and make sure that he only commits to the folder he wants.

Comment: I think the submodule may work better. I haven't worked much with the new contractor so I'm a little weary about giving him access and letting him commit to the right branch. Once i understand his working style a little more, that may be the simpler option.

Comment: If you are on github, you can let him commit whatever he wants to *his* repo.  When he is ready to commit hiw work, he can submit a pull request and you will be able to review his code before you pull it into the  *main* repo

Answer (score 7):

I haven't done this, but seems like maybe you have 2 options:

1) Grant the contractor pull access (but not push) to the repository.  They can then fork it, do their work on their fork (probably within a branch?) and then send you pull requests and you would need to pull his/her changes in.  Downside is that the contractor can't get code released to the server without your intervention (that could be an upside, depending).

2) If their work is isolated to one subtree, use two repositories and [make one a submodule of the other](http://help.github.com/submodules/).  You can then set the access control differently in the 2 repositories, but you get a unified view of the project.

Comment: I think this might work. Would he have read access to the main repo? I only want to give him full rights to the submodule repo. I guess the main thing i'm trying to do is to autodeploy.

Comment: Yes, he would.  Again, take this with a grain of salt; I haven't actually done it.