# With git: Can I let other people work on just one file without let them see the other files of the code?

Tags: git

I am new to git but everything is working fine so far. I wonder how to realize this:
I have a project containing several files with subroutines. I want to let other people work with only one specific file. Without git I copied the object files and only the source of the file on which they should work on. Now with the git I want to create a new Branch. In this Branch only one file should be able to be edited. All other file should be invisible. Is this possible? A link is enough if this is an easy question, but i have not found anything on google.

Thank you for your advice,

M.

Comment: This is very similar to the thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418705/github-restricting-access. Said thread is one of the first things that came up on Google when I searched "git restricting access"

Answer (score 2):

You could perhaps make a git submodule that just includes that file. This means that the file is in a separate git repository with separate access/push access, but it'll be incorporated into the larger project when you update the submodules.

http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules