# How can I setup Granular Access to our Codebase / Git Repos?

Tags: git, github

We have a Git repo that is currently including Backend processing scripts, Front end design, api endpoints, etc. (we host it on github)

All front end use our namespaced classes, admin backend even references them.

So folders may be

```
/frontend/Classes/
/frontend/Views/
/frontend/example.com/public_html
/backend/Classes/
```

We use DeployHQ as a method of deploying Stage and Master branches to our various server(s).

I would love folder specific permissions. (Not happening). So what would be the simplest way to set this up. I dont want a designer with Repo access to whole project, but the ability to change minor things on publichtml/views; (master autodeploys to our ELB).

Any advice?

Comment: How about creating separate repositories and then integrate them as a big one using `git submodules`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Github restricting access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418705/github-restricting-access)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is DeployHQ, but with git I will probably use `git submodule`

Say I have two folders in my project `fA`, `fB`. and a developer `A`, a designer `B`.

I want `A` to have full access to both repositories, but `B` can only push to `fB`.

I'll first create two repositories `repoA`, `repoB`.

And I'll give `A` **both** repositories **push** access(or even force push access). Then I'll give `B` `repoA`'s **read** access **only** and `repoB`'s **push** access.

Then I'll create a integrate project called `repoTop`. And I'll add `repoA` and `repoB` as submodules of `repoTop`. The access of `repoTop` really depends, if you have a guy who's job is releasing software, then probably just give him push access to `repoTop` and read access to `repoA` and `repoB`. Point is the guy who has push access to `repoTop` should be the one in charge of releasing the project.

Then designer `B` can read/use all the code but he can not push the code to `repoA`. Best thing is if designer `B` wrote some improvements of `repoA`(yes, not a typo here). Although he can't push to `repoA`, but he can create a pull-request and developer `A` can review and decide if he want to merge it.

For `git submodule`, check [this](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) link.