# How to prevent other user to change code in file regarding GIT and Visual Studio 2013

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, version-control

suppose i my main project code is in Github and my team member clone that project in their pc and open with Visual Studio for coding purpose.i guess at same time two person can made the change in same file. just guide me can i prevent this? is there any option available in Visual Studio 2013 to prevent two user to work on same file. long time i work with VSS and this kind of provision is there.

if this kind of provision is there in Visual Studio 2013 and GitHub as source control then please share the knowledge. thanks

Comment: The entire point of Git, or any version control tool for that matter, is so two people _can_ make a change to the same file in different places.

Comment: This issue is similar, but not a duplicate, of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13662255/is-there-a-way-to-lock-individual-files-or-directories-on-fork-when-using-github

Comment: See [this SO article](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9418705/github-restricting-access) for a clever way to use submodules to restrict access of certain parts of a project.